# OpenContainer with Scoped Model not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, scoped-model

Since scoped model has its own scope, it seems it breaks the usage of OpenContainer with the default provided code. It gets a cannot find scope error when this is there:

```
OpenContainer(
                  transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fadeThrough,
                  closedBuilder:
                      (BuildContext _, VoidCallback openContainer) {
                    //_SelectedProductState.productName = "St. Ives® Scrubs";
                    return Card();
                  },
                  openBuilder: (BuildContext _, VoidCallback __) {
                    return ScopedModel<DownloadImages>(
                      model: downloadImages,
                      child: WidgetHere(),
                    );
                  },
                  onClosed: (_) => print('Closed'),
                ),
```

Perhaps there should be a modification in the `BuildContext` variables, but I have no idea what to do, maybe even a descendant. What should I do to fix it?

The transition and widget opening works, but during the animation the error occurs and the image in my `Card` gets the red error.

Note: I have a `ScopedModelDescendant` in this `Card` widget, and the console shows that's where the error is, it seems it gets the wrong model when the animation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, but not this. I simply moved on to the Provider package, it did the job without any errors, seems way more powerful and convenient. My luck that I stumbled upon Scoped Models first.